# Can Ironpython be used to run multiple Python Virtual Machine Instances in parallel?

Tags: python, ironpython

Inspired from the game [GunTactyx](http://apocalyx.sourceforge.net/guntactyx/), where you write programs controlling fighting robots. Guntactyx used the Small language, that later is called Pawn.

I am looking into using Python as the scripting language.

My concerns are:

1. Interfacing to C# The scripts
   should interface into C# through
   simple functions, doing stuff like
   scanning for enemies, rotating and
   firing. I guess each function should
   be delayed, so they would take x ms
   to return.
2. Bad programs. The system should
   be tolerant to infinite loops or
   crashes. I would like each virtual
   machine to be given X ticks to
   execute at a time.
3. Limited memory usage Scripts
   should not be allowed to use
   unlimited usage. I would like some
   sort of cap.
4. Probably alot of other problems

I would like to end up with something in this "pseudo" style.

```
robots = a list of robots

while(1)
   foreach robot in robots
      robot.tick()
   gameworld.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your subject question is *yes*, you can run multiple interpreters in parallel. Generally each script will run in its own `ScriptScope`, but you can also use isolated `ScriptEngine`s if necessary.

1. You can inject variables/functions into a script's scope before running it using `scope.SetVariable`.
2. Your best bet is to run the Python code on a separate thread and watch it; if it takes too long to return, interrupt the thread. <sub>(this is tricky to get right, but that's a different question)</sub>
3. I'm not sure that can enforced easily. It may be possible if you run the scripts in a different AppDomain or process, but that's a lot of extra work for minimal gain.
4. Just ask!

Comment: It is critical that each Virtual Machine has same amount of computing cycles. Do you think there is a way to let it run in a controlled fashion?

Comment: The same number of processes, probably not, at least not on .NET. The best you could do is given them a fixed time window.